# Installing project.json compatible .net-core sdk on ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, .net-core

I'm trying to install .NET Core on Ubuntu. I'd like a version that supports project.json (as I'm still using that).

I followed the steps here.
https://www.microsoft.com/net/core#linuxubuntu

In particular, this:

`sudo apt-get install dotnet-dev-1.0.1`

That seems to give me a version that doesn't support project.json.

Is there an apt-get installable version of dotnet-dev that supports project.json?

Thanks!
Ranj

Comment: `project.json` is dead; I'm not sure you'll be able to find support for it any more.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try changing your install command to:

```
sudo apt-get install dotnet-dev-1.0.0-preview2-1-003177
```

The downloads are versioned based on the SDK. The SDK that supported `project.json` is verioned as `preview`. The 1.0.1 SDK supports csproj only.

Comment: That did it. Thank you!